# Button in wp_nav_menu for slide

Tags: wordpress, button

I currently have a separate button from my navigation menu that turns the menu on and off, but I would like to put this button at the end of the navigation bar

So here is the html / php part of wordpress, precisely the header.php

```
<nav class="main-nav">
                <button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="main-menu" class="togle">Menu</button>
                <?php 
                wp_nav_menu(
                    [
                        'theme_location'=>"menu-du-header",
                        'items_wrap'    => '<ul id="main-menu" class="menu" hidden>%3$s</ul>'
                    ]
                );
                ?>
            </nav>
```

Here is the JS part which allows you to display and dispense the menu

```
const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.main-nav button');
const menu = document.querySelector('#main-menu');

toggleMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const open = JSON.parse(toggleMenu.getAttribute('aria-expanded'));
  toggleMenu.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !open);
  menu.hidden = !menu.hidden;
});
```

And here is the CSS part which concerns the navigation bar and the button

```
.main-nav button {
    position: relative;
    font: 0/0 a;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 2.4rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: content-box;
    transition: .3s;
}
.main-nav button::before,
.main-nav button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.4rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: .3s;
    transform-origin: left;
}
.main-nav button::before {
    top: 0;
}
.main-nav button::after {
    bottom: 0;
}
.main-nav button[aria-expanded=true] {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.main-nav button[aria-expanded=true]::before {
    transform: translate(.5rem, -.375rem) rotate(45deg);
}

.main-nav button[aria-expanded=true]::after {
    transform: translate(.5rem, .375rem) rotate(-45deg);
}
.main-nav .menu{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    transform: translateX(-90%);
    transition: .3s;
}
.main-nav .menu:not([hidden]) {
    transform: translateX(0)
}
.main-nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #020504;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
.main-nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: var(--primary);
```

[image: What I want]

Comment: here are some pictures 

[navigation closed][1]
[navigation open][2]
[what i'm looking to do ][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JfHB.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRo6Y.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KueuJ.png

Comment: Please provide more information and add css/js code too.

Comment: I think it's good :) I hope there is enough information!

Comment: Why don't you just move the button after the `wp_nav_menu` function?

Comment: Why isn't the button fixed to the top left corner?

Comment: Whether I place the button before or after the `wp_nav_menu` function, it does not make any change

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do @Flexy

Comment: @d3LTa7, ok then, what about:
`.main-nav button { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }`

Comment: I want to put the button in the bar as in the image and have the cross on the far right when the menu is open!

Comment: See the image I added

Comment: Nobody can help me ?